# how to make anaconda use my default python?

Tags: python, anaconda

## how to make anaconda use my default python?

## Useful infos

I'm working on 2 pcs one having win10 and the other having a fresh win 11 pro installation.
alongside anaconda I'm using VScode to develop in python, Django, PHP, laravel, js, react. and help me synchronize my settings between both pcs
I installed python3.11 and everything is well configured with VScode (database connection, etc), I also installed pipenv
[image]

## main

as u see I have 2 python environments already installed
I want to remove the python installed in anaconda and I found a way to do so(I will explain it)
**but I don't know how to make anaconda use my global python located in Program Files\python311**
however, anaconda has a lot of packages, and **I don't know if replacing thepy3.9 installed with them by the systems py3.11 will work or not**

[removing the python package from anaconda](https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-install-uninstall-python-packages-in-anaconda-virtual-environment-successfully/)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, where did you get Python 3.11 from ? If it was from the built-in App Store from Microsoft, you should deinstall it. This installation is buggy as hell, and you should consider getting 3.11 from somewhere else.

Secondly, Anaconda will manage the packages for you, so you should install Anaconda once with 3.11 and re-download all the packages you need.

Comment: I installed py 3.11 from the official website
and I don't seem to understand your comment
are you suggesting that I uninstall conda and then reinstall it and it will automatically use the default python I have?